# how to use the `query` method to check if elements of a column contain a specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to check if a column contains a string.  My preffered method is to use `.str.contains`.  However, that returns a boolean array that I have to use as a mask on the original dataframe.  The convenience of `query` is that it returns the already filtered dataframe.

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list('abcdefghijklmno')).reshape(5, 3),
                  columns=list('XYZ')).add('w')
df
```

[image]

Using `str.contains`

```
df[df.Y.str.contains('b')]
```

[image]

But I have a preference to use `query`

```
df.query('Y == "bw"')
```

[image]

The problem is, I don't know how to use `query` to check for substrings.  I wanted something similar to this.

```
df.query('Y like "b%"')
```

Comment: Looking at [pandas.eval](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval), it doesn't seem to support `in` or function calls (so `re.match` or `.startswith` won't work). I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not supported, `query` only implements a subset of operations, basically none of the string functions.

Just a sidenote to the comment, `query` does support a vectorized version of the `in` keyword.

```
df.query('X in ["aw", "dw"]')
Out[9]: 
    X   Y   Z
0  aw  bw  cw
1  dw  ew  fw
```